# How can I retrieve a subcollection in firestore with spring framework?

Tags: java, spring, google-cloud-firestore, spring-cloud

I have a database stored on Firestore with the following structure:

```
-Collection
----Document
-------Subcollection
----------Documents with Data
----Document
-------Subcollection
----------Documents with Data
----Document
-------Subcollection
----------Documents with Data
```

I want to retrieve the documents located in the subcollection but I can't seem to be able to with the following code:

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document(collectionName = "states")
public class State {

    @DocumentId
    String name;

    int num_of_listings;
    Flux<Listing> listings;
}
```

The code for Listing is:

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document(collectionName = "listings")
public class Listing {

    @DocumentId
    String id;

    String description;
}
```

Imagine each "State" contains some "Listing"s. Each POJO is accompanied by a controller with a repository injection of type `FirestoreReactiveRepository` like the following:

```java
@Repository
public interface StateRepository extends FirestoreReactiveRepository<State> {
}
```

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/states")
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class StateController {

    private final StateRepository stateRepository;

    @GetMapping
    private Flux<State> getAllStates() {
        return stateRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

When I'm requesting all the states with `getAllStates()` I get a null `listings` field while all other fields are initialized, as expected. How can I possibly achieve the desired functionality?

@Edit: If there is a way to access the subcollection directly, it is also welcome!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it doesn't work because you are using a field of type Flux in your entity class.

```java
Flux<Listing> listings;
```

But the project does not support collections of this type currently. Try using `List<Listing>` instead.

Edited:

Your entity class should look like that:

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document(collectionName = "states")
public class State {
    
    @DocumentId
    String name;
    
    int num_of_listings;

    List<Listing> listings;
    
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't result in any change (still getting null). Could you elaborate on the `project does not support collections of this type currently` ? I'm not understanding it due to the fact that the `FirestoreReactiveRepository` is an extension of [`ReactiveCrudRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/reactive/ReactiveCrudRepository.html) which returns a collection of type `Flux<T>` when the method `findAll()` is called.

Comment: To clarify, the project does not support Flux as a collection type within an entity class. See the [documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-gcp/1.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#supported-types-3) to see the list of supported types.

Comment: @Invalid_Path please take a look at this [sample app](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/blob/master/spring-cloud-gcp-samples/spring-cloud-gcp-data-firestore-sample/) and specifically at the [entity class](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/blob/master/spring-cloud-gcp-samples/spring-cloud-gcp-data-firestore-sample/src/main/java/com/example/User.java). It demonstrates how collections can be used as fields in Firestore entities.

Comment: I formatted my code to be exactly like the one you provided but I'm still getting a `Null` value returned when I send the request from Postman. I found this [thread](https://gitter.im/spring-cloud-gcp/Lobby?at=5e41773f1d23aa47aa068565) which I'm guessing you participated in and while it seems that, as Daniel Zou places it, subcollections might not have been supported. Unfortunately, this thread is over 2 years old and I can't find the issue #2189 that Oskar Olsson says you posted, so I can't verify if it was actually implemented (and if it was an issue at all, actually).

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm getting a `Null` value only on the List<> field. The rest of the fields are retrieved normally.

Comment: I ended up using this [approach](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/f5fcf50e8f626929d0e06816ec6715898327e231/firestore/src/main/java/com/example/firestore/snippets/RetrieveDataSnippets.java#L135-L141) and creating a FirestoreService Component which is created at initialization by Spring and querying it indirectly.

Comment: @Invalid_Path it was implemented. The sample works for me and saves and loads the collection. Maybe try running it and see if it works for you.

Could you create a minimal app that replicates the issue (maybe on github) so I can examine it more closely? Also feel free to create an issue on [our tracker](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/issues).

Answer (score 0):

Try `@DBRef(db="listings")`

```
 @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Document(collectionName = "states")
    public class State {

        @DocumentId
        String name;

        int num_of_listings;
        @DBRef(db="listings")
        Flux<Listing> listings;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still getting a `null` value on my `listings` field.